# OpenAPI generator: wrong format for the example value of date datatype. Is it possible to customize?

Tags: swagger-ui, openapi, springfox, openapi-generator, api-doc

I am using **openapi-generator** of the latest version (**4.2.2**) for generation of Java Spring API. Configuration looks like this:

```
openApiGenerate {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "${projectDir}/src/main/resources/api/users-spec.yaml"
    outputDir = "${buildDir}/generated/open-api"
    apiPackage = "com.example.accounts.api"
    invokerPackage = "com.example.accounts.handler"
    modelPackage = "com.example.accounts.model"
    modelNameSuffix = "Json"
    configOptions = [
            delegatePattern: "true"
    ]
}
```

I found out that definitions containing datatypes of `date` with example values produce differently formatted values in the output Java models.

```
definitions:
  User:
    properties:
      birthday:
        description: Date of birth
        type: string
        format: date
        example: "2020-01-01"
```

The generated model is:

```
  @ApiModelProperty(example = "Wed Jan 01 03:00:00 MSK 2020", value = "Date of birth")
  @Valid
  public LocalDate getBirthday() {
    return birthday;
  }
```

After the creation of swagger ui with **springfox (2.9.2)** I am having an example request as `{"birthday": "Wed Jan 01 03:00:00 MSK 2020"}`. It is confusing because a standard Jackson date deserializer cannot deserialize such value. Can I have an example value in **yyyy-mm-dd** format?

Comment: I have the same problem...

Comment: Same problem....

Answer (score -2, accepted):

i found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61082113/bug-in-openapi-generator-wrong-format-for-the-example-value-of-date-datatype)

```
birthday:
    description: Date of birth
    type: date
    format: yyyy-mm-dd
    example: "2020-01-01"
```

Comment: If your solution is not yours, you should share the link in a comment section.