# openapi java generator serializes LocalDate as array instead of full-date

Tags: java, openapi, jackson-databind, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using the OpenAPI java generator [1] with library:resttemplate, dateLibrary:java8 in a spring project to generate a client from a spec.

For a property in the spec:

```yaml
        targetDate:
          type: string
          format: date
```

the following code is generated:

```java
  public static final String JSON_PROPERTY_TARGET_DATE = "targetDate";

  private LocalDate targetDate;

  @javax.annotation.Nonnull
  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_TARGET_DATE)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)

  public LocalDate getTargetDate() {
    return targetDate;
  }

  @JsonProperty(JSON_PROPERTY_TARGET_DATE)
  @JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)
  public void setTargetDate(LocalDate targetDate) {
    this.targetDate = targetDate;
  }
```

I would expect this field to be serialized to a full date e.g. "2023-01-01" as promised by the spec: https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.0#data-types. However it is in fact serialized to an array: `[2023,1,1]`.

Similarly another property

```yaml
        otherDate:
          type: string
          format: date-time
```

is serialized to seconds since epoch, instead of full-time. (I assume this is a bug in the generator)

I cannot add any annotations since the code is generated. How can I still ensure that the date is properly serialized?

[1] openapi-generator-maven-plugin 6.3.0

Answer (score 6):

Your issues are not generator related, they are Jackson related.

Regarding your DateTime being in the wrong format, this is the default way that Jackson will serialize a `LocalDate` object when it uses the `JavaTimeModule`.  This is discussed on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423389/force-jackson-serialize-localdate-to-array), when the user is specifically asking for an array serialization.  This can be fixed by setting the format you want, which is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72444033/6860078).

The basic gist is this.  You need to set the `@JsonFormat` annotation above your field. You say that you cannot add any annotations, but this is also incorrect.  You can easily add the `@JsonFormat` annotation to your code by setting the [`x-field-extra-annotation` extension](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/#supported-vendor-extensions) in your schema.  For example:

```yaml
targetDate:
  type: string
  format: date
  x-field-extra-annotation: '@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat(shape = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")'
```

This will result in the following code being generated

```java
@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat(shape = com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
private LocalDate targetDate;
```

As for the `date-time` being serialized as seconds since epoch, this is a vary easy setting in Jackson.  You can disable the `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`.  This will result in the ISO-8601 standard string.

Comment: I maintain that this is a generator bug, as I expect the generator to add the appropriate Jackson annotations. I did not know about `x-field-extra-annotation`s, thanks! Why do you propose a different solution for `date-time`? Is it also possible to use an `x-field-extra-annotation` there?

Comment: This is not a bug, but a conscious decision on the part of the developers.  You said you are using the `java` generator with the `resttemplate` library.  By default, the `resttemplate` library generates a class called `RFC3339DateFormat`, and a class called `JavaTimeFormatter`.  You can examine the code in the `ApiClient` and see how the formatters are used, and you can also easily add your own format to them by modifying the mustache templates used to generate the formatters and the `ApiClient`.

Comment: Solution is working fine except with bad input in request the system (spring) return SERVER_ERROR instead of BAD_REQUEST. Did you have this issue?

Comment: Found the solution need to catch the exception when getting the field. It seem to do the parsing when I call the getter. So simple and well done

Comment: How can I easily add something to a schema if I'm integrating to some service, which is the point of using openapi? I don't have the schema under control...